# How to insert QGIS project properties "Project Title" as field or token using an expression?

Tags: print-composer, qgs, title

Using QGIS, the "General" project properties dialogue includes a "Project Title" area.

Is it possible to use the information inserted in this dialogue in an expression (specifically including within a label when using Composer)?

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS 2.8, here's how I can get the project title into a text element in a map composer.

Add text element, hit "Insert an expression..."

Go to the Function Editor tab, create a new file, call it "project", and put this in it:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
def projtitle(value1, feature, parent):
    proj = QgsProject.instance()
    return proj.title()
```

Hit the green arrow button to run and that will check the syntax. Save it. Now you should have a new function you can put in the expression editor (in the Custom group), for example:

```
 [% projtitle( 0 )%]
```

in the text field for Map Composer text objects replaces it with the title from the settings.

I couldn't get it to work with no arguments, so the 0 is just a dummy.

Here's a screengrab of the various components showing it in action.

[image: project title insertion]

Answer (score 1):

This has been implemented in QGIS 2.14's composer within the expression builder that is called by the 'Insert an expression' button when a text box is active.

They are called 'variables' now and you can call a great variety of them with the syntax "[% @qgis_version %]" right in the text box. The expression builder will also take care of those brackets and percent signs for you, if you can enter a valid expression. [image: Variables in QGIS print composer].

Please see Nyall Dawson's great blog posts about variables in QGIS:

- Part 1: http://nyalldawson.net/2015/12/exploring-variables-in-qgis-2-12-part-1/
- Part 2: http://nyalldawson.net/2015/12/exploring-variables-in-qgis-pt-2-project-management/
- Part 3: http://nyalldawson.net/2015/12/exploring-variables-in-qgis-pt-3-layer-level-variables/